# Cron not sending email

Tags: cron

I have installed **PostFix** and **sendmail** both,
and then try to set cron for a python script and want to send an email by cron.

My cron schedule like:

```
MAILTO=test@example.com
*/2 * * * * python3 /var/test.py >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1
```

Still Cron is not sending any email.

Please help what i need to do more.

Answer (score 4):

Cron will send the STDOUT and STDERR from the script by email.

> ```
> >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1
> ```

… but your script has redirected them both to a file so there isn't any data to send.

Remove the redirect if you want the data to appear in an email instead.

Comment: So i need to remove ">> /var/log/test.log 2>&1" from cron?

Comment: Still its not working. Do i need to setup any sender email configuration on server .

Comment: Not beyond the normal set up of the server. If you can send and recieve email normally, then it should be fine.

Comment: How to check its sending and receiving email normally or not, Can u send me any command to check it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have sendmail installed. on some mimimal raspibian/Pi OS installs it is missing by default

Answer (score 3):

I've been fighting this problem on a new CentOS 8 installation.  I found a reply to this blog posting, https://bobcares.com/blog/crontab-not-sending-email/ where the poster suggested reinstalling "cronie"

```
yum reinstall cronie
```

and that worked for my situation.

Comment: That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Rocky 8 here, same issue. Mailing worked after installing `sendmail` and restarting `crond`: `dnf install -y sendmail && systemctl restart crond.service`.

Answer (score 0):

After setting MAILTO, you should run the command `newaliases` to let the system update settings.

Also, you have to remove the `>> /var/log/test.log 2>&1` part, as this will log the output into the logfile, leaving nothing to email.

If you just want to have the error messages in the email, remove just the `2>&1` part.

Comment: "After setting MAILTO, you should run the command newaliases to let the system update settings" — No. Absolutely not. That's for setting up new email addresses on the system. i.e. so you can receive email at a different address. It is not for telling cron where to send email to.

Answer (score 0):

## /var/log/mail.err

Check this file to see if you have errors:

```
/var/log/mail.err
```

### Example

#### error

In my case it was happening on Ubuntu 22 despite installing `mailutils` and `postfix`, and not having an error in `/var/log/syslog` about `No MTA installed`

```
$ tail -f /var/log/mail.err

Jan  9 17:41:16 me-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[276051]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
```

#### Cause

I installed postfix with "No configuration".

#### Solution

I could change this using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix` (Credits: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519519 )

Answer (score 0):

After installation of `s-nail` and `sendmail` in CentOS 9, I had to restart `crond.service` to receive cron job's log over email.

(@cyqsimon already put this as a comment above)